# SQL Server in App_Data MVC

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I just created a SQL Server Database in my App_Date by right clicking -> Add new Item -> SQL Server (Not compact).

I have created a model with the necessary data.

How do I go about sending data to that database? I don't mind using any method i.e. Linq/EF etc.

Comment: Design time or runtime? Design time - double click on it and use the server explorer tool window. Run time - use entity framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best you open the sql server compact sdf file by double clicking it. Here you will be able to modify the database tables / columns etc.

Next add a new project item. Select Entity Framework database and go through the guided wizard.